# Animation for/in jquery added text

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add animation to the class "text-to-right" in the following code:

```js
$(".newul li").on("click", function() {

  var myval = $(this).html();
  var newtext = "dummy text";

  $(".someclass").html(myval + "<span class='text-to-right'>" + newtext + "</span>");
});
```

```html
<div class="someclass"></div>
<ul class="newul">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

The HTML for the class "someclass" appears fine. But how can I make the `newtext` appear with some animation?

Comment: What kind of animation?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ check this out.

Comment: How can i add `.animate()` inside the `.html(....animate()  ..)`. @showdev .. any kind of animation. say fadeIn for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want any simple effect to make it more smooth try initial hide with CSS and then show with `fadeIn()`from Jquery :

```js
$(".newul li").on("click", function() {
  var myval = $(this).html();
  var newtext = "dummy text";
  $(".someclass").html(myval + "<span class='text-to-right'>" + newtext + "</span>").slideDown();
  $('.text-to-right').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.text-to-right, .someclass {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someclass"></div>
<ul class="newul">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Hiding it first with css and animating it from jQuery is the trick! Question: why did you add `.slideDown();` at the end of the jquery code? Its not running right?

Comment: @Somename that slidedown just animate the entire someclass the first time it's called